# hovering over image too fast does an glitch

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Im trying to display some divs when the user hovers over another div and Im trying to use fadeIn and giving the speed for it too. Im also trying to move another div. The code is as follows -

```
 $('#boardpicture2').hover(function() {

    $('#boardpicture3').stop().animate({'margin-left': '200px'},500 );
        $('#boardpicture6').fadeIn(1000);
}, function() {
     $('#boardpicture3').stop().animate({'margin-left': '0'},1000 ); 
     $('#boardpicture6').fadeOut(500);
});
```

But now if I try to hover over the div really fast(I mean if I move the mouse out of the div before the fadeIn is completed then the boardpicture6 disappers and then appears back and then fades out. Can you tell me if there is a way to check if the fadeIn is completely done and only then call the fadeOut function.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you make a sample for it? a fiddle. :)

Answer (score 0):

`stop` the animation before doing this. Read about stop jQuery function [here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). You have to stop the animation to ensure that the previous animation completed.

Also if you want to fadeOut() something, do it like this

```
$(something).hide().fadeOut();
```

This will ensure that the element is hidden while the fadeOut function is called.
In short,

```
$(something).stop().hide().fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force jQuery stop complete the existing animations `fadeIn` by using [.stop(true, true)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$('#boardpicture2').hover(function() {
    $('#boardpicture3').stop().animate({'margin-left': '200px'},500 );
    $('#boardpicture6').stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000);
}, function() {
    $('#boardpicture3').stop().animate({'margin-left': '0'},1000 ); 
    $('#boardpicture6').stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
});
```